# Coefficient of $x^n$ in series

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I am trying to find the coefficient of $x^n$ in the series
$$S(X) = x^3 \sum_{n=0} (n+1)x^n$$

I got that this further equals $$\sum_{n \geq 3} (n-2)x^n$$ so the coefficient is $(n-2)$, for $n \geq 3$, but this does not seem to be correct. Could someone tell me if I made a mistake? Also, how would do this if I want to keep the summation at $n \geq 0$

Comment: "but this does not seem to be correct" Why do you think so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is correct, it's just that the derivation is a bit confusing because you use $n$ both as a free variable and as a bound summation variable. It would be clearer to say that you're looking for the coefficient of $x^n$ in

$$
x^3\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1)x^k\;.
$$

That also makes it easier to reason about the coefficient without shifting the summation variable, as you can now require $x^3x^k=x^n$, yielding $k=n-3$ and thus the coefficient $(n-3)+1=n-2$.